# XMPP MUC returns error code 401 when joining or creating room, in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xmpp

When I send the request to create the room to `XMPP server(Openfire)` I am getting error code `401` from the server. Below are the logs for the same:

```
"2013-09-03 09:47:56:298 ChatsIphone[7133:3e13] SEND:  type="get" to="test2@conference.shan.com" id="CD5FD987-039D-47D8-AF97-83212E68B14E">query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner"/>

2013-09-03 09:47:56:299 ChatsIphone[7133:4a0f] SEND: presence to="test2@conference.shan.com/iphone1">x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"><password>iphone1/password>/x>x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update">photo/>/x>c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework" ver="VyOFcFX6+YNmKssVXSBKGFP0BS4="/>/presence>

2013-09-03 09:47:56:358 ChatsIphone[7133:4a0f] RECV: iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="CD5FD987-039D-47D8-AF97-83212E68B14E" from="test2@conference.shan.com" to="iphone1@shan.com/7cffdf9">query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner"/>error code="401" type="auth">not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>/error>/iq>
```

And also I can see that my room is created. But I am not able to resolve the error code 401.
can any one let me know what is the problem here.

Vaz

Hi Adam,

Thanks for the responce,

Please find below the code,

The room is created succesfully with below code,

```
XMPPJID *roomRealJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:_userNameEdit.text];
XMPPRoom *newXmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_appDelegate.xmppRoomStorage jid:roomRealJid dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)];
[newXmppRoom activate: _appDelegate.xmppStream];
[newXmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
[newXmppRoom addDelegate:_appDelegate delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[newXmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:_appDelegate.xmppStream.myJID.user history:nil password:@"iphone1"];



- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{
         [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
}
```

Thanks,
Vaz

Comment: Could you post the code that you are using to send the request please